# Understanding Java Stream with Function as Parameter

Tags: java, java-stream, functional-interface

I am using Java in my project. I see code like below and not able to understand the flow.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person p1 = new Person("test1");
    Person p2 = new Person("test2");

    List<Person> l = List.of(p1, p2);
    var count = l.stream().filter(checkMethod(Person::getName)).count();
    System.out.println(count);
  }

  public static final <T> Predicate<T> checkMethod(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
    final var seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    return t -> seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
  }

Person.java
 public class Person {

  Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  private String name;
   //getters and setters for name
  }
}
```

It identifies the count of unique name from list of person objects. I see check method is called only once. But usually filter method will be executed for each items in list.

Is it like entire list of persons is sent to check method and called only once?

Comment: Your `checkMethod` creates a predicate. It is that predicate that is called multiple times, not the `checkMethod`.

Comment: There is `distinct()` method for streams which can be used here.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look what `.filter(checkMethod(Person::getName))` actually does and how it works:

- At first `checkMethod(Person::getName)` is executed and returns a Predicate, which is the argument required for the [`filter(..)` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-)
- then, `filter(t -> seen.add(t.getName()))` is executed for every item on the stream
- As [`Collection.add(..)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add-E-) returns a boolean indicating whether the element as added, every item is removed whose name was already seen

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain how Person::get Name got converted to filter( -> seen.add(t.getName) ?

Comment: This article explains method reference in Java including some examples with lambdas: https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-references

Answer (score 1):

`checkMethod()` generates a *stateful* predicate.

While executing `checkMethod()` JVM evaluates the lambda expression (*lambdas are always evaluated at Runtime*) and creates an instance of a *Functional interface* (`Predicate`) which captures the reference to the `Set` `seen`. I.e. local variable `seen` in the method would vanish when the method terminates, but the `Predicate` would hold the reference to this object to it, so the `Set` alive until the predicate is alive.

> But usually `filter` method will be executed for each items in list.

`checkMethod()` would be called **only once**.

And each stream element would be checked against the instance of `Predicate` returned by `checkMethod()` using `Predicate.test()` (*i.e. functional method returning a* `boolean` *value, not your custom method* `checkMethod()`).

In other words, method `test()` would be invoked on the predicate for every element in the stream, but invocation of `checkMethod()` would occur only one and each element would be checked against the same predicate.

So, you're confusing the creation of a `Predicate` via `checkMethod()`, and validation of elements via `Predicate.test()`.

Comment: So, final var seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet(); will not get initialized for each element ? It will get executed once for the stream ? or else set will be emptied for each item.

Comment: @Lolly Sure, method generating a `Predicate` would be evaluated only once and the Lambda expression defining the `Predicate` would capture the reference to the `Set`. The method frame containing local variable `seen` would be kicked out from the stack when the method returns, the Set would continue to leave as part of the Predicate since it holds a reference to it. And every stream element would be checked against the **same** stateful predicate, using `Predicate.test()` (**not** `checkMethod()`). Therefore, Set would contain information about every unique element which has passed the `filter`

Answer (score 1):

Let's talk with code.

```java
var count = l.stream().filter(checkMethod(Person::getName)).count();
public static final <T> Predicate<T> checkMethod(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
    final var seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    return t -> seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
}
```

is the same as the following code:

```
var predicate = new Predicate<Person>(){
    final var seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    public boolean test(Person p){
        return seen.add(p.name);
    }
}
var count = l.stream().filter(predicate).count();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why or hoe final var seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet(); is outside of test method ?